# HTTP Sampler settings error while testing desktop based application using Jmeter 5.0

Tags: jmeter, desktop, recording

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wp5Fx.png)

Steps performed for performance testing of desktop-based application(add-in in Ms word 2016) using Jmeter:
1) File->Template-> Create
2) Https Test script recorder-> Port number 8888 
3) Changed the proxy setting port number of the desktop to 8888
4) Click on start button in jmeter.
5) got this message as in the screenshot.
6) Open the word file and start clicking on the ribbon.
Nothing gets recorded in jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter 5.0 release notes](http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html)

> Recording feature has been improved to provide a popup that is always on top when you navigate in browser allowing you to name transactions while you navigate in your application.

[image: JMeter 5.0 release notes]

So the pop-up is absolutely expected.

---

The fact you are not able to actually record is frustrating, here are some troubleshooting steps you might want to take:

1. JMeter is only capable of recording HTTP and HTTPS protocols, if your add-in uses other transport - you will not be able to record the traffic. c
2. For recording HTTPS requests you need to install JMeter's self-signed certificate into your operating system trusted storage. Given you've mentioned MS Word add-in I assume you're on Windows so make sure to import `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` file into [Windows Certificate Management tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/certmgr-exe-certificate-manager-tool). Also see **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) article to learn more about the concept of [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) proxy.

   [image: JMeter Desktop Apps Certificate Manager]
3. You might need to [set system-wide proxy via netsh command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc731131(v=ws.10)#BKMK_2) so your add-in could pick it up

   [image: JMeter WinHTTP Proxy for Desktop Apps]

Check out [How to Run Performance Tests of Desktop Applications Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-desktop-applications-using-jmeter) article for more detailed explanation of the above techniques if needed.